# Compare & Sort an array of Char in C++

Tags: c++, c, sorting, char, compare

We are learning C++ at the moment and I don't think this code requires us to use pointers yet.

So, for suggestion to the answer, please let me know if it can be done without pointer or not.

Question: How to compare an array of char so that you can sort them in ascend order?

Details:

Goal: Sort the name in ascending order as they are inserted

What we have here:

```
char name[1024]; // which is a part of a Struct
```

The insertion works. Once it is inserted. I am trying to rearrange the order so that the names are in

ascending order.

I have:

```
if (RecordCollection[i].name > RecordCollection[i+1].name) // for comparing
```

I think this might be where the problem is? Can C++ compare like that? Like, comparing John with Amy with

that one line?

```
After that if statement, I am using swapping the elements so they are in correct order. For example: 
If John[0] the current name is > than Amy[1], then copy John to a temporary. 
Then copy Amy to index[0]. 
Then copy John in temporary to index[1].
```

While typing this question, I think I need to compare the char one by one... J with A, if not the same then

sort. If same, move onto next char until it finds something different to sort. But then I don't know how to

get the char 1 by 1.

Comment: Please don't talk about "C/C++" as one language - they're not, in fact they're stylistically very different. Mixing them conceptually does you no favours.

Comment: Your code already is using pointers.  There's very little you can do with an array without causing decay to pointer.  For example `RecordName[i]` is actually doing `*(i + (record_type*)RecordName)`.

Comment: Since the answers would be radically different for C or C++, you should probably pick a language.

Comment: @Flexo, sorry I meant I can use either C or C++ implementation for this. The file is .cpp if that is phrased better.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Possibly not.  Since he starts out by saying he's learning C++, the instructor may have forbidden use of `std::string` in order to teach about arrays.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Ops. Wrong code. I meant RecordCollection. RecordCollection is a struct Record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using strings, see `strcmp`.

> #### man `strcmp`
>
> A value greater than zero indicates that the first character that does not match has a greater value in `str1` than in `str2`; a value less than zero indicates the opposite.

To sort your array, you can also use `qsort` from the standard C library.

```
#include <string.h>

int
cmp (const void *p, const void *q)
{
  return strcmp (p, q);
}

qsort (RecordName, nelems, 1024, cmp);
```

Comment: Note that it won't work if the `char[]` are not null terminated.

Comment: BTW, "Goal: Sort the name in ascending order **as they are inserted**" calls for insertion sort, not quicksort.

Comment: @BenVoigt: BTW, it is not guarantee that `qsort` uses quicksort. I was just giving a sorting technique in the general case.

Comment: Since he is learning, and this seems to be an assignment, using library functions is probably not what the instructor wants.

Comment: @Kirilenko: It is guaranteed that `qsort` sorts when you call it, not as each item is inserted.

Comment: @BenVoigt: though suboptimal, quicksort should work foe this task.

Comment: @MooingDuck: No, it really can't.  It only sorts items already in the array, it doesn't find where a new item should be placed.

Comment: @BenVoight: Op said he has already inserted the new item into the list, and just needs to aort it into place.  Quicksort after each insert is slow, but works.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the feedback. I appreciate the help. After reading about @Kirilenko's response on strcmp, I was able to get further than my original process. So I was really happy thanks :].

Comment: @crashmstr, you are right. I don't think the instructor wants library functions. But I appreciate all kind of feedback as it helps me learning. I wasn't able to give a heads up about the library since I didn't know it existed. I thought we have to manually write it.